# Using React Context as part of useEffect dependency array for simple toast notification system

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm building a simple toast notification system using React Context. Here is a link to a simplified but fully working example which shows the problem https://codesandbox.io/s/currying-dust-kw00n.

My page component is wrapped in a HOC to give me the ability to add, remove and removeAll toasts programatically inside of this page. The demo has a button to add a toast notification and a button to change the `activeStep` (imagine this is a multi-step form). When the activeStep is changed I want all toasts to be removed.

Initially I did this using the following...

```
useEffect(() => {
  toastManager.removeAll();
}, [activeStep]);
```

...this worked as I expected, but there is a react-hooks/exhaustive-deps ESLint warning because toastManager is not in the dependency array. Adding toastManager to the array resulted in the toasts being removed as soon as they were added.

I thought I could have fixed that using `useCallback`...

```
const stableToastManager = useCallback(toastManager, []);
useEffect(() => {
  stableToastManager.removeAll();
}, [activeStep, stableToastManager]);
```

...however, not only does this not work but I would rather fix the issue at the source so I don't need to do this every time I want this kind of functionality, as it is likely to be used in many places.

This is where I am stuck. I'm unsure as to how to change my Context so that I don't need add additional logic in the components that are being wrapped by the HOC.

```
export const ToastProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [toasts, setToasts] = useState([]);

  const add = (content, options) => {
    // We use the content as the id as it prevents the same toast
    // being added multiple times
    const toast = { content, id: content, ...options };
    setToasts([...toasts, toast]);
  };

  const remove = id => {
    const newToasts = toasts.filter(t => t.id !== id);
    setToasts(newToasts);
  };

  const removeAll = () => {
    if (toasts.length > 0) {
      setToasts([]);
    }
  };

  return (
    <ToastContext.Provider value={{ add, remove, removeAll }}>
      {children}

      <div
        style={{
          position: `fixed`,
          top: `10px`,
          right: `10px`,
          display: `flex`,
          flexDirection: `column`
        }}
      >
        {toasts.map(({ content, id, ...rest }) => {
          return (
            <button onClick={() => remove(id)} {...rest}>
              {content}
            </button>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </ToastContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const withToastManager = Component => props => {
  return (
    <ToastContext.Consumer>
      {context => {
        return <Component toastManager={context} {...props} />;
      }}
    </ToastContext.Consumer>
  );
};
```

Comment: Sorry if I missed some context, but 'add toast' doesn't work for me on your example app

Comment: Or rather, it briefly makes something flash up on the screen, which i assume isn't the intended behavior

Comment: Apologies, I've updated the sandbox now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to "Fix it from the core", you need to fix `ToastProvider`:

```
const add = useCallback((content, options) => {
  const toast = { content, id: content, ...options };
  setToasts(pToasts => [...pToasts, toast]);
}, []);

const remove = useCallback(id => {
  setToasts(p => p.filter(t => t.id !== id));
}, []);

const removeAll = useCallback(() => {
  setToasts(p => (p.length > 0 ? [] : p));
}, []);


const store = useMemo(() => ({ add, remove, removeAll }), [
  add,
  remove,
  removeAll
]);
```

Then, the `useEffect` will work as expected, as the problem was that you re-initialized the `ToastProvider` functionality on every render when it needs to be a singleton.

```
useEffect(() => {
  toastManager.removeAll();
}, [activeStep, toastManager]);
```

Moreover, I would recommend to add a custom hook feature as the default use case, and providing wrapper only for class components.

In other words, do not use wrapper (`withToastManager`) on functional components, use it for classes, as it is considered an anti-pattern, you got `useContext` for it, so your library should expose it.

```
// @ toastContext.js
export const useToast = () => {
  const context = useContext(ToastContext);
  return context;
};

// @ page.js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useToast } from './toastContext';

const Page = () => {
  const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = useState(1);
  const { removeAll, add } = useToast();

  useEffect(() => {
    removeAll();
  }, [activeStep, removeAll]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Page {activeStep}</h1>

      <button
        onClick={() => {
          add(`Toast at ${Date.now()}!`);
        }}
      >
        Add Toast
      </button>

      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setActiveStep(activeStep + 1);
        }}
      >
        Change Step
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Page;
```

[image: Edit intelligent-lake-2j51q]

Comment: This works a charm if like you said I use a custom hook, which I will start doing, but if I use the HOC i appear to get the same functionality as before with the toasts being removed straight after being added.

Comment: You need also memoize the value provided to `Provider`, check the updated answer and the sandbox with a working example